# Linq and Lambda expression for a complex sql query involving joins

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

Using Linq to Entity (Entity Framework) in MVC 3 project.

My model:

Table - Users
UserID (PK)
...

Table - Clients
ClientID (PK)

Table - PropertyItems
PropertyItemID (PK)

Table - MemberContactPreference (Contains PropertyItems selected by Users- many to many)
UserID(FK)
PropertyItemID(FK)

Table ClientProperties (Contains PropertyItems that belong to Clients - many to many)
ClientID (FK)
PropertyItemID (FK)

**I want to list all the distinct users that have selected all the properties selected by clients.**

My Approach :

I got a list of all properties for a particular client in

```
Iqueryable<ClientProperty> clientProperties  = GetClientProperties(ClientID)

Iqueryable<User> UsersMatchingClientProperties = GetAllUsers();



foreach (ClientProperty property in clientproperties)
{

 UsersMatchingClientProperties = (from uem in UsersMatchingClientProperties
                                  join ucp in GetAllMemberContactPreferences on 
                                  ucp.UserID == uem.UserID
                                  where uem.MemberContactPreferences.SelectMany(      
                                  mcp => mcp.PropertyItemID == property.PropertyItemID)
                                  select uem).Distinct;
}
```

It gives the right result only first time. As it doesn't reduce the number of items in UsersMatchingClientProperties with each iteration. actually it replaces the collection with new resultset. I want to filter out this collection with each iteration.

Also, any suggestions to do this in Lambda expression without using Linq.

Thanks

Comment: Im not too sure I understand what you are trying to do but one thing i notice is that you arent enumerating the set when you get it back. This means its staying as queriable, use `GetAllUsers().ToArray()` and `GetClientProperties(ClientID).ToArray()` to ensure these sets are in memory before the next query, as it stands this will execute on the db which i dont think is what you are intending

Answer (score 1):

That generation of an iqueryable in a for loop seems like a dangerous thing, which could end up in a monster sql join being executed at once.

Anyway, I don't think you need that. How about something like this?

```
// for a given client, find all users 
// that selected ALL properties this client also selected

Iqueryable<ClientProperty> clientProperties  = GetClientProperties(ClientID)

Iqueryable<User> allUsers= GetAllUsers();

Iqueryable<MemberContactPreference> allMemberContactProperties = GetAllMemberContactPreferences();


Iqueryable<User> UsersMatchingClientProperties = allUsers
.Where(user => allMemberContactProperties
               .Where(membP => membP.UserID==user.UserID)
               .All(membP => clientProperties
                           .Select(clientP => clientP.PropertyID)
                           .Contains(membP.PropertyID)
               )
);
```

Here is an alternative query in case you want the users that selected ANY property for a given client

```
// for a given client, find all users 
// that selected ANY properties this client also selected

Iqueryable<ClientProperty> clientProperties  = GetClientProperties(ClientID)

Iqueryable<User> allUsers= GetAllUsers();

Iqueryable<MemberContactPreference> allMemberContactProperties = GetAllMemberContactPreferences();


Iqueryable<User> UsersMatchingClientProperties = clientproperties
.Join(allMembersContactProperties, // join clientproperties with memberproperties
      clientP => clientP.PropertyItemID, 
      membP   => membP.PropertyItemID,
      (clientP, membP) => membP)) // after the join, ignore the clientproperties, keeping only memberproperties
.Distinct()                       // distinct is optional here. but perhaps faster with it?
.Join(allUsers,                   //join memberproperties with users
      membP => membP.UserID,
      user  => user.UserID,
      (membP, user) => user))     // after the join, ignore the member properties, keeping only users 
.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

I trust Hugo did a good job suggesting ways to improve your query (+1). But that does not yet explain the cause of your problem, which is the modified closure pitfall.

I think that after your loop there is some code that actually executes the query in `UsersMatchingClientProperties`. At that moment the query is executed *with the last value of the loop variable `property`*! (The loop variable is the closure in each query delegate that is created in an iteration, and it is modified by each iteration).

Change the loop like this:

```
foreach (ClientProperty property in clientproperties)
{
    var property1 = property;
    ...
```

and use property1 in the query. That should solve the cause of the problem. But as said, it looks like the whole process can be improved.

Comment: right, an [outer variable trap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx), good call! Hopefully that will be fixed in net 5.0

Comment: It seems they do: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx